# How to send message activity from Web Chat Bot to Microsoft Teams channel

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-qna-maker

I have created a Echo Bot in c# using QnA maker which is working absolutely fine now I wanted to achieve a scenario where if user ask any question and bot unable to find related answer than this question must be sent on Microsoft Teams channel where except will reply to the same and that message will sent to the user.

So, **Is there any way to send message user message to Microsoft Teams** for expert reply. If you have any sample code for the scenario please feel free to mention.

Answer (score 0):

As per your current requirement this is kind of handoff or human live agent connect.

The following way you can achieve posting a message in ms team ( Go through this article [Send proactive messages to Teams channels and users](https://www.vrdmn.com/2020/02/microsoft-bot-framework-v4-send.html) ).

1. Send proactive messages to Teams channels and users ( Microsoft Bot Framework v4 )
2. The user should be part of ms teams ( Azure AD valid users ).

**Suggestions :** If you are using domain bot then human live agent or handoff concept is the best approach otherwise you can integrate bin search api or any other third party api for unanswered question.

Answer (score 0):

As per your requirement you can use Graph API to send message to channel using below code

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var chatMessage = new ChatMessage
{
    Body = new ItemBody
    {
        Content = "Hello World"
    }
};

await graphClient.Teams["{team-id}"].Channels["{channel-id}"].Messages
    .Request()
    .AddAsync(chatMessage);
```

Please go through this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp) for more info.

Comment: Hi @Navin Tiwari Please let us know does that help clarify?